# Escaping Issues

Tags: escaping

I have some questions about escaping.These examples are the things which I couldnt do the true.

**Must I escape variables, if it is, how can I do it?**

For example: `global $redux_demo;`

in this code:

```
if ( class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
    global $redux_demo;
if ($redux_demo['button-set-single-archive-services'] == 2)
{
    get_template_part( 'demo-archive-services' );
    die;
```

**Is it true escaping?**

```
<?php esc_html_e( 'Our Services', 'hekim' )?>
```

**Functions start with the, need escaping or not?**

For example : `<?php the_title(); ?>`

If I change these functions with the functions start with `get`, do they need escaping? 
Is there any difference about output with functions start `the` and functions start `get`?

**Why this escaped function doesnt seem?**

After escaped this phare, it doesnt seem.What is my mistake in escaping? What is the true form?

```
<li><?php esc_html( '<a href="#"> HOME </a>' ); ?>xx</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of escaping is to make sure that when a value is output, it cannot output anything malicious, or that would just break the markup of the page. For example, when outputting a variable, you will want to escape certain characters so that the value can't unintentionally open or close HTML tags, which could break the layout of your page, or even output a `<script></script>` element that could run malicious JavaScript.

WordPress VIP's documentation has a great overview of the concept, with examples: https://wpvip.com/documentation/vip-go/validating-sanitizing-and-escaping/

Regarding your specific examples:

> **Must I escape variables, if it is, how can I do it?**
>
> For example: `global $redux_demo;`
>
> in this code:
>
> ````
>     if ( class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
>         global $redux_demo;
>     if ($redux_demo['button-set-single-archive-services'] == 2)
>     {
>         get_template_part( 'demo-archive-services' );
>         die;```
> ````

No. Not all variables need to escaped. Variables only need to be escaped when output. `$redux_demo` is not being output, so nothing here needs to be escaped.

> **Is it true escaping?**
>
> ````
> <?php esc_html_e( 'Our Services', 'hekim' )?>```
> ````

Yes. `_e()` is a function that allows the `'Our Services'` string to be replaced by a translation. This means that you can't trust that the output of this line will always be safe. Therefore it needs to be escaped. `esc_html_e()` is a function that automatically escapes with `esc_html()`, after running `_e()` to allow the text to be translated.

> **Functions start with the, need escaping or not?**
>
> For example : `<?php the_title(); ?>`
>
> If I change these functions with the functions start with `get`, do
>   they need escaping? Is there any difference about output with
>   functions start `the` and functions start `get`?

As a general rule, built in functions that start with `the_` don't need to be escaped, but functions starting with `get_` *do* need to be escaped. For example, `the_permalink()` uses `esc_url()` to escape `get_the_permalink()` before outputting it.

> **Why this escaped function doesnt seem?**
>
> After escaped this phare, it doesnt seem.What is my mistake in escaping? What is the true form?
>
> `<li><?php esc_html( '<a href="#"> HOME </a>' ); ?>xx</li>`

The point of `esc_html()` is to prevent any HMTL in the value from being interpreted as HTML. There is nothing in this example that needs to be escaped. If the link URL was a variable, *that* would need to be escaped.

Comment: hey, you are the only person helps me here.can you look at this question:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367280/small-escaping-sanitization-issues